# Image manipulation dlib argparse.ArgumentParser() problem?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

We are working on a project with my friend, but we still haven't gotten through a big problem. We tried many things but could not fix the problem. the problem is related to "argparse.ArgumentParser().

**error part :**

```
usage: detect_drowsiness.py [-h] -p SHAPE_PREDICTOR [-a ALARM] [-w WEBCAM]
detect_drowsiness.py: error: the following arguments are required: -p/--shape-predictor
```

**codes part:**

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-p", "--shape-predictor", required=True,
    help="path to facial landmark predictor")
ap.add_argument("-a", "--alarm", type=str, default="",
    help="path alarm .WAV file")
ap.add_argument("-w", "--webcam", type=int, default=0,
    help="index of webcam on system")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(args["shape_predictor"])
```

**file content:** shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat and detect_drowsiness.py(file name)

Why does this problem exist?

Answer (score 1):

If you notice,

```
ap.add_argument("-p", "--shape-predictor", required=True,
    help="path to facial landmark predictor")
```

-p/--shape-predictor argument is required. So, you should do the following when you run the python file:

```
python detect_drowsiness.py -p shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat
```

or

```
python detect_drowsiness.py --shape-predictor shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat
```

Comment: I am grateful to you. Thank you.. :) I have to do this every time I want to open the program. Is there any other way? Can I pass it into codes or define this argument?